# Convenções de escrita para controles em ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, estilo-de-codificação, controles

Quando você arrasta um controle da Toolbox para um Web Form o Visual Studio automaticamente adiciona um ID para este controle que consiste em seu tipo com primeira letra maiúscula e um número.

Esse é o mesmo padrão utilizado em projetos em VB.NET com Windows Forms, mas quando você está utilizando C# com Windows Forms o Visual Studio coloca a primeira letra minúscula e o mesmo ocorre naquele padrão (notação húngara) bastante utilizado que consiste em abreviar o tipo (ex. em C#: txt, btn, cmb, etc).

Então por que quando estou fazendo um projeto em ASP.NET utilizando C# o padrão seguido é o do VB.NET? Existe alguma convenção de escrita para controles em ASP.NET? Qual é a mais utilizada por profissionais da área?

Comment: O tal padrão se chama "notação húngara". Ver [artigo da wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) (em inglês, a versão pt é bem ruim), e http://support.microsoft.com/kb/173738/en-us (também em inglês).

Comment: vlw por me lembrar cara, adicionei à pergunta o nome correto.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Existe alguma convenção de escrita para controles em ASP.NET?

A Microsoft possui uma convenção de escrita para suas linguagens.

- [Naming Guidelines - .NET Framework 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Esta documentação recomenda:

> - Use **PascalCasing** para todos os nomes públicos consistidos de múltiplas palavras de membros, tipos e namespace.
> - Use **camelCasing** para nomes de parâmetros.

Answer (score 0):

Somente a título de conhecimento, existe um documento bem interessante desenvolvido pelo pessoal da [dotnetspider](http://www.dotnetspider.com/), elaborado com base nas recomendaçõe da Microsoft e o contribuições da comunidade.
http://www.dotnetspider.com/tutorials/bestpractices.aspx

Comment: Bem vindo a nossa comunidade, o correto é que este espaço seja reservado somente a respostas efetivas, o ideal é que o seu conteúdo seja postado em forma de comentário! ;D